# how to make dropdown option width to adjust to it's longest content using bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, css, autocomplete, dropdown, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to apply an [autoComplete](https://github.com/TarekRaafat/autoComplete.js) feature on my web app but I can't seem to find a way to make the options to adjust to the longest content.

the only thing I can do is to make it into a fixed length using this css:

```
.autocomplete-suggestions li {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

but then the content of the option would get cut off.. how do I make it show the entire content instead?

Comment: Not sure were you'd find an element `.autocomplete-suggestions`, the demo under https://tarekraafat.github.io/autoComplete.js/demo/ does not appear to contain anything like that. The UL used there to display the suggestions is positioned with `left:0; right: 0` - not sure if `.autoComplete_wrapper > ul { right: auto !important; }` is what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work as I hope after tinkering with the css before and I'd like to share a bit what I found out. hopefully this answer will help someone in need.

I used these css:

```
.autocomplete-suggestions {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: visible;
}
.autocomplete-suggestions li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

the html structure are more or less like this:

```
<div class="autocomplete-suggestions">
  <li class="suggestion" role="option">my name</li>
  <li class="suggestion" role="option">this is a longer version of my name</li>
  <li class="suggestion" role="option">this is a shorter content</li>
</div>
```

I'm still not 100% sure which css rules made it work.. but hey, as long as it works, right?